# How to achieve fixed header in web page?

Tags: css

So i'm trying to do something like this:
https://choosemypc.net
where the top of the image is still showing even though you are scrolling down.

Currently I just have a static image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position: fixed;` on the image. It is similar to `absolute`, but is positioned relative to the browser window instead of to the document.

**Edit:** Your CSS reveals that you are using a background image instead of an `<img>` tag. You should use `background-attachment: fixed;`

Comment: position:fixed; seems to mess up the whole page.

Here's a jfiddle i created: https://jsfiddle.net/wo25nLx7/ (it's in hebrew so don't mind that)

Comment: I can't diagnose reliably unless you post you html and css, but it's likely because you need to set the height on the image's container.

Comment: I posted the css and html, it's here : https://jsfiddle.net/wo25nLx7/

Thanks for the help!